# ¿Cómo validar un combo a través de un botón en otro formulario?

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo que validar un combo que lo arma dentro de una función y esa función está en otro formulario.

Quiero que en mi formulario al darle un botón me valide ese combo que está en otro formulario a través de una función. ¿Cómo seria?

Esta es la función que arma el combo en el formulario a.

```
function uf_load_tiposolicitud($as_seleccionado,$rtipo)
{
    $lb_valido=true;
    $ls_sql="SELECT codtipsol, dentipsol, estope, modsep, estayueco".
            "  FROM sep_tiposolicitud ".
            " ORDER BY modsep, estope  ASC ";   
    $rs_data=$this->io_sql->select($ls_sql);
    if($rs_data===false)
    {
        $this->io_mensajes->message("CLASE->Solicitud MÉTODO->uf_load_tiposolicitud ERROR->".$this->io_funciones->uf_convertirmsg($this->io_sql->message)); 
        $lb_valido=false;
    }
    else
    {
        print "<select name='cmbcodtipsol' id='cmbcodtipsol' onChange='javascript: ue_cargargrid();' style=width:200px>";
        print " <option value='-'>---seleccione---</option>";
        while($row=$this->io_sql->fetch_row($rs_data))
        {
            $ls_seleccionado="";
            $ls_codtipsol=$row["codtipsol"];
            $ls_dentipsol=$row["dentipsol"];
            $ls_modsep=trim($row["modsep"]);
            $ls_estope=trim($row["estope"]);
            $ls_estayueco=$row["estayueco"];
            $ls_operacion="";
            switch($ls_estope)
            {
                case"R":// Precompromiso
                    $ls_operacion="Precompromiso";
                    break;
                case"O":// Compromiso
                    $ls_operacion="Compromiso";
                    break;
                case"S":// Sin Afectacion
                    $ls_operacion="Sin Afectación Presupuestaria";
                    break;
            }
            if($as_seleccionado==$ls_codtipsol."-".$ls_modsep."-".$ls_estope."-".$ls_estayueco)
            {
                $ls_seleccionado="selected";
            } 

            print "<option value='".$ls_codtipsol."-".$ls_modsep."-".$ls_estope."-".$ls_estayueco."' ".$ls_seleccionado.">".$ls_dentipsol." - ".$ls_operacion."</option>";

        }
        $this->io_sql->free_result($rs_data);   
        if($rtipo==1){
            print " <option value='98'>RENDICIÓN</option>";
            print " <option value='99'>REPOSICIÓN</option>";
        }
        print "</select>";
    }
    return $lb_valido;
}// end function uf_load_tiposol
```

Mi función en el formulario b:

```
function ue_print()
{ 
    if((txtfecreghas.value)<(txtfecregdes.value))
    {
        alert ("La fecha Desde no puede ser mayor a la fecha Hasta");
    }
    else
    {
        f=document.formulario;
        ls_numsoldes=f.txtnumsoldes.value;
        ls_numsolhas=f.txtnumsolhas.value;
        window.open("reportes/sigesp_cxp_rpp_solicitudes_ejecucion_presupuestaria.php?numsoldes="+ls_numsoldes+"&numsolhas="+ls_numsolhas,"catalogo","menubar=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,width=1000,height=800,left=50,top=50,location=no,resizable=yes");
    }

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tu pregunta no se entiende. Trata de explicar mejor lo que quieres, llamando las cosas por su nombre. ¿Cuál es el select que quieres validar? ¿Qué entiendes tú por validar un select?... *Quiero que en mi formulario* **¿qué formulario?** *al darle un boton* **¿qué botón?** *me valide ese combo* **¿qué combo?** *que esta en otro formulario* **¿qué formulario?** *a traves de una funcion* **¿qué función?** ...O sea, llamar las cosas por su nombre. Y si es posible di lo que has intentado, qué dificultades tienes, etc.

Comment: ¿Has probado a usar `document.getElementById('cmbcodtipsol')` para acceder al contenido de ese menú desplegable ("combo")? ¿Qué has probado hacer? ¿Qué es lo que no te funciona? ¿Qué dato quieres comprobar? ¿Cuáles son los rangos de valores correctos o lo que da validez a la selección?